# Quotient of abelian groups of rank $2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $A, B$ be abelian groups, $B$ is contained in $A$, both $A$ and $B$ are assumed to have rank $2$. Is there a standard way to show that the quotient group $A/B$ is finite? I think there exists some general theorem about modules finitely generated over a PID, but i can't find the precise theorem i need to apply, so even a simple reference would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the theorem you want is that there is a generating set $x,y$ for $A$ and there are non-negative integers $e$ and $f$ such that $ex,fy$ is a generating set for $B.$ Then $[A:B] = |ef|$. This should be proved (in somewhat greater generality) in any algebra text that treats modules over a PID.

Comment: so using your notations, we have $A=\mathbb{Z}x+\mathbb{Z}y$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}ex+\mathbb{Z}fy$. Now what happens to the quotient: $A/B=....$. I suppose it is direct sum of $ef$ finite summands, how to find out them?

Comment: I think it is clear that $\{ ix + jy : 0 \leq i \leq e-1, 0 \leq j \leq f-1 \}$ is a set of coset representatives for $B$ in $A.$